# Opening Word files from HTTP links in Outlook

Tags: ms-office

If I have an email in Outlook containing a link like https://example.com/Document.docx and I click it, it gives me a warning dialog "Do you want to open the file? Some files harm your computer blah blah blah". I click yes and it starts Word, but then nothing. No error message, no document, it's just as if I started Word manually.

If I right-click the link and select `Open URL` it opens it in Chrome and downloads the file which is slightly better.

I did also try running `"/Applications/Microsoft Word.app/Content/MacOS/Microsoft Word" "https://example.com/Document.docx"` from the command line but it gives a dialog with the error:

> Word cannot open the document: User does not have have access privileges (Document.docx)

Is there any way to have Word actually open the file? Or alternatively to make clicking a link behave the same way as right-click->Open URL?

Comment: The best you're going to get is to download it then open it. On the website you have no rights to the document at all, so you must work on a local copy.

Comment: I have the right to open it. Word handles read-only files fine normally - it provides a 'Duplicate' button to create a local writable copy.